# How to subtract elements in a DataFrame

Tags: sparkr

In SparkR I have a DataFrame `data` contains `id`, `amount_spent` and `amount_won`.

For example for id=1 we have

```
head(filter(data, data$id==1))
```

and output is

```
1 30 10
1 40 100
1 22 80
1 14 2
```

So far I want to know if a fixed id has more won  than losses. The amount can be ignored.

In R I can make it to run but it takes time. Say we have 100 id's. In R I have done this

```
w=c()
for(j in 1:100){
# Making it local for a fixed id 
q=collect(filter(data, data$id==j))
# Checking the difference. 1 means wins and 0 means losses
if( as.numeric(q$amount_won) - as.numeric(q$amount_spent)>0 {
w[j]=1 
}
else{w[j]=0}
}
```

Now w simply gives me 1's and 0's for all the id's. In sparkR I want to do this a more faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure wether this is exactly what you want, so feel free to ask for adjustments.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1),
                 amount_spent = c(30,40,22,14),
                 amount_won = c(10,100,80,2))

DF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)
DF <- withColumn(DF, "won", DF$amount_won > DF$amount_spent)
DF$won <- cast(DF$won, "integer")

grouped <- groupBy(DF, DF$id)
aggregated <- agg(grouped, total_won = sum(DF$won), total_games = n(DF$won))

result <- withColumn(aggregated, "percentage_won" , aggregated$total_won/aggregated$total_games)

collect(result)
```

I have added a column to DF whether the ID has won more than he spent on that row. The result has as output the amount of games someone played, the amount of games he won and the percentage of games he won.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. How should one count the total number of won=FALSE and TRUE as well ?

Comment: Counted the total number of games, total of won games and percentage of won games.